# Error while starting Apache

Tags: perl, apache, web-applications, perl-module

I am getting following error while starting apache.

```
Can't locate /usr/sbin/webmux.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 . /etc/httpd) at (eval 2) line 1.\n
Can't load Perl file: /usr/sbin/webmux.pl for server 127.0.0.1:0, exiting...
```

Can anyone please suggest me what i am missing ?

mod_perl-2.0.4

Comment: Sounds a bit more like a Serverfault question. It appears to be a bug in the mod_perl Apache Module. Which version are you using?

Comment: `webmux` belongs to [RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/). Start troubleshooting in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in RT configs. After comment it, things are working now.

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like webmux.pl needs the mysql daemon started first. I found the error message in /var/log/httpd/error_log. Start mysqld first and then the web server will start

Answer (score 0):

Search your Apache config files for webmux.pl.  Something must be trying to load it.  Either remove the reference to it, or install it.

Comment: That depends on what it is, which hopefully would be hinted at by whatever was trying to load it.  Apparently, it's part of RT, which I've never tried to install.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
[root@localhost conf]# service httpd restart
Deteniendo httpd:                                          [FALLÓ]
Iniciando httpd:                                           [FALLÓ]
[root@localhost conf]#
```

Log:

```
[error] Can't load Perl file: /usr/sbin/webmux.pl for server localhost.localdomain:0, exiting...
DBI connect('dbname=rt3;host=localhost','rt_user',...) failed: Access denied for user 'rt_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /usr/share/perl5/DBIx/SearchBuilder/Handle.pm line 106
```

Solution:

```
[root@localhost conf]# mkdir /root/backup/httpd/ -p
[root@localhost conf]# mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/rt3.conf  /root/backup/httpd/
[root@localhost conf]# service httpd restart
Deteniendo httpd:                                          [  OK  ]
Iniciando httpd:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@localhost conf]#
```

Answer (score -1):

here is what i found on http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/Troubleshooting
**Can't locate Apache/Response.pm in @INC ... 
Can't load Perl file: bin/webmux.pl for server localhost:0, exiting...**

```
Found this issue in Aurora SPARC Linux 2.0 (Fedora Core 3 for SPARC) 
when trying to install... 
turns out that after installing all the modules for rt, 
I still had an ancient verion of CGI.pm, 
which was not intended to correctly detect the mod_perl2 modules vs. 
regular mod_perl. Upgrading CGI via CPAN quickly resolved this problem after an 
embarrassing number of hours troubleshooting.

If Apache refuses to start after you add PerlRequire bin/webmux.pl to your 
config and you're sure you've got a valid mod_perl2 installation, 
try upgrading CGI to the latest version.
```

maybe you can try first to update your CGI.pm module.

Did you find your call to webmux.pl in your apache conf ?

---

old previous useless response :

well, can you post the code from the script that tries to launch webmux.pl ?

but i would suggest a simple solution, if you don't have administrative rights or don't want
to go further in your perl conf :
add at top of your code (but below  use strict...never forget this one)
in your script the code :

```
use lib "/usr/sbin/"
```

so you script will be able to use libraries located in /usr/sbin/

Comment: I have admin rights and there is no webmux.pl available at /usr/sbin

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, i read a bit fast your post, and didn't noticed it was at apache startup.
Search throught your apache conf : httpd.conf, sites-available/default and so on (all your conf file or .htacces files)
to find a reference to webmux.pl. 
you can try a "grep -nori webmux *" in your apache conf directory for easier search

Comment: giving me a "-1" doesn't tell me if you found a call for webmux.pl in your conf.
Did you searched for it ?

Comment: ok, no prob anyway.
Did you manage to do anything ? did you find the call to webmux in your apache conf ?